# CocoaPods install an old version of framework

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

CocoaPods - 1.1.1

My pod file looks like this:

> target 'MyNewProject' do
>
> pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 5.0'
>
> pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
>
> end
>
> use_frameworks!

`XLPagerTabStrip` library is installed with an old swift version and xcode propose me convert it up to 2.3 or 3.0. This issue is noticed with other swift libraries e.g. Reactive Cocoa

Thank you!

Comment: update pod so newer version will get installed

Comment: @NarendraPandey with no result(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mintioned in [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) - [Change Log](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> 6.0.0
>
> Swift 3 support

So updating its pod to the latest version should let it supports Swift 3 by default.

You can add it as `pod 'XLPagerTabStrip'` without specifying the version number, which causes to get latest version (it's the default behavior if you are not specifying the version number).

Change: `pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 5.0'` to `pod 'XLPagerTabStrip'`

As mentioned, you should get version 6.0.0 (latest version).

Finally, your pod file should look like:

> target 'MyNewProject' do
>
> pod 'XLPagerTabStrip'
>
> pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
>
> end
>
> use_frameworks!

*Recap*: After making sure that the latest version of a library has been released to support -for example- Swift 3, install it without specifying the version number; Each time you'll update the podfile, it will automatically install the latest version of the pod.

For more information, you can check [Podfile Syntax Reference](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod).

Hope this helped.